# PHP array_intersect / array_diff / combine array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr[] = array('title' => 'Overview');
$arr[] =array('title' => 'General');
$arr[] =array('title' => 'History');
$arr[] =array('title' => 'Construction');
$arr[] =array('title' => 'Plan');
$arr[] =array('title' => 'Other');

$info_arr[] = array("title" => "General", text => "value1");
$info_arr[] = array("title" => "History", text => "value1");
$info_arr[] = array("title" => "Construction", text => "value1");
$info_arr[] = array("title" => "Plan", text => "value1");
```

I need to be able merge these arrays together.So they look something like this. As I will need to loop thru the consolidated array. *Other, Overview* do not have any text values but still need to placed into the array.

```
$new_arr[] = array("title" => "General", text => "value1", "title" => "History", text => "value1", "title" => "Construction", text => "value1"
,"title" => "Plan", text => "value1","title" => "Overview", text => "","title" => "Other", text => "");
```

I have tried for loops (using count value), foreach loops, I thought array_intersect or array_diff don't see to solve the issue. This should not be so difficult, but I'm trying to piece together some really bad legacy code. Or the cube/florescent lights might have finally got to me.

Update:

```
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $arr[] = array("title" => $Title);
}
```

and

```
while ($dstmt->fetch()) {
   $info_arr[] = array("title" => $descriptionType, "descriptiontext" => $descriptionText); , "descriptiontext" => $val );
      }
```

$dstmt & $stmt are queries.

I thought this would work but not so much

```
$r = array_intersect($arr, $info_arr);
var_dump($r);
```

*Something like this* Let me clarify:

```
$new_arr = array(array("title" => "General", text => "value1"),
    array("title" => "History", text => "value1"),
    array("title" => "Construction", text => "value1"),
    array("title" => "Plan", text => "value1"),
    array("title" => "Overview", text => ""),
    array("title" => "Other", text => "")
);
```

Comment: It's not possible to have duplicate array keys, `$new_arr[] = array("title" => "General", text => "value1", "title" =>` will not work, as `title` is duplicate at the same level.

Comment: Your `something like this` is incorrect, an impossible array.  Edit your question to show what you actually want.  Construct the array manually if you have to.

Comment: What sort of "join" do you want to enforce?  Do you want all records in `$arr` and only matching records (based on title) from `$info_arr`?  What is there is a title in `$info_arr` that doesn't exist  in `$arr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with these two arrays, you can just use the title as the key in `$r`.

```
foreach (array_merge($arr, $info_arr) as $x) {
    $r[$x['title']]['title'] = $x['title'];
    $r[$x['title']]['text'] = isset($x['text']) ? $x['text'] : '';
}
```

Or, you can go back a step and avoid having separate arrays by building the `$r` array in the same manner as you fetch your query results:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $r[$Title] = array('title' => $Title, 'text' => '');
}
while ($dstmt->fetch()) {
    $r[$descriptionType] = array("title" => $descriptionType, "text" => $descriptionText);
}
```

Or, ideally, you could go back another step and avoid having separate queries by using a `JOIN` to get the same results in one query, but there's nothing in the question on which to base any specific suggestion for that.

Comment: I didn't actually implement the PHP answer. The problem I was initially having was because I was using 2 queries, then trying to sort them out in php. But based @Don'tPanic answer, it was better to to solve the problem in the sql query. I used JOIN, NOT IN and combined it all with UNION.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the exact `$new_arr` you're requesting isn't possible. However, I think this will give you a similar result that should work for your purposes:

```
foreach ($info_arr as $infoArray) {
    $found = array_search(array('title' => $infoArray['title']), $arr);
    if (false !== false) {
        unset($arr[$found]);
    }
}
$new_arr = array_merge($info_arr, $arr);
```

It works by removing the "duplicates" from the original `$arr` before doing the `array_merge()`.

If it's important to add an empty `text` value for the remaining items in `$arr`, do this before the `array_merge()`:

```
foreach ($arr as &$arrArray) {
    $arrArray['text'] = '';
}
```

The resulting array will look like this:

```
$new_arr[] = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'General', 
        'text' => 'value1', 
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'History', 
        'text' => 'value1', 
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Construction', 
        'text' => 'value1',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Plan', 
        'text' => 'value1',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Overview', 
        'text' => '',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Other', 
        'text' => '',
    ),
);
```